# Guess My Number Game JOptionPane (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, joptionpane

I'm new to coding and need some help with this Guess My Number game. Any help would be greatly appreciated. How do I get the user's input to be checked with the random number. Also, how do I allow the user to play again after the game is over. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

//Ryan Kuri
//Mar 3, 2015
//Description:
//
public class GuessMyNumberJOP
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Font font1 = new Font ("Cooper Black", Font.PLAIN, 30);
   Font font2 = new Font ("Chalkduster", Font.PLAIN, 36);

   UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.WHITE);
   UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.BLACK);
   UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", Color.BLACK);
   UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", font1);
   UIManager.put("TextField.font", font2);

   ImageIcon myIcon = new ImageIcon(GuessMyNumberJOP.class.getResource("images.jpg"));

   String name1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
         "Enter Your Name:",
         "Number Guess",
         JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
         myIcon,
         null,
         "");

   AudioClip mySound = Applet.newAudioClip(GuessMyNumberJOP.class.getResource("cheering.wav")); 

   mySound.play(); 


   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, " + name1 +  "!  ");



   Random random = new Random();
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int min = 1;
   int max = 10;

   int number = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
   int guesses = 0;

   AudioClip explode = Applet.newAudioClip(GuessMyNumberJOP.class.getResource("Copy of explosion-01.wav")); 

   explode.play();

   String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
   int guesser = Integer.parseInt(num);


   do{

       guesses++;
       if (guesser > number)
       {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My number is less than: " + guesser);
          guesser = Integer.parseInt(num);
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess again: ");
       }

       else if (guesser < number)
       {
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "My number is greater than: " + guesser);
          guesser = Integer.parseInt(num);
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess again: ");
       }

       else 
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number + " WAS THE NUMBER --- " + "YOU GOT IT IN " + guesses + " GUESSES");

   } while (guesser != number);

   System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest assigning the Random method to a variable, and then performing IF Statements based on that variable.

e.g:

```
                Random rand = new Random();

                int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(10) 

                if randomNumber == 9 {
                //Do this

                }
                else {

               }
```

10 being the top of the range, so that it will pick any random number between 0-9.

Hope this helps!